# Почему падает исключение в методе вызова следующей middleware?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Тот код, что после await next() не вызывается в обоих случаях, так как в 35 строчке падает исключение. Вывод в браузере "To next middleware.To next middleware." Я ожидаю "To next middleware.To next middleware.After next middleware.After next middleware."

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("To next middleware.");
        await next(); //28 line
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("After next middleware.");
    });

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("To next middleware.");
        await next(); //35 line
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("After next middleware.");
    });
}
```

Под отладкой заметил, что в консоли вывода имеется такое сообщение с исключением. Попробовал выставить у ctx.Response.StatusCode это не привело к изменению поведении.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.<>c.<Build>b__18_0(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
   at Platform.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__1_1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\illub\Desktop\learn\ProNetCore3\Ch12_Platform\Platform\Startup.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Platform.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__1_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\illub\Desktop\learn\ProNetCore3\Ch12_Platform\Platform\Startup.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

В чем мое непонимание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в конце цепочки фреймворк [добавляет](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/18d261b20c2e7f23ebd1971a8ce2fa701be757e0/src/Http/Http/src/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L83-L100) следующий код:

```cs
            RequestDelegate app = context =>
            {
                // …

                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
```

Смысл тут в том, что если вы дошли до конца цепочки - значит, ни один обработчик не "признал" запрос за подлежащий обработке. А значит, нужный адрес не найден и надо возвращать 404. Вот именно этот возврат 404 и выбрасывает исключение, ведь нельзя менять заголовки после записи в Response.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не определен терминальный middleware.
На 35 строчке вызов next() пытается получить его, а так как его нет Asp.Net Core пытается установить StatusCode (404) для ответ. Но StatusCode можно установить только для нового ответа, в который еще ничего не было записано (можно отслеживать по флагу `ctx.Response.HasStarted`).Так как вы уже начали туда писать, строка 27 `ctx.Response(...)`, ответ помечается запущенным (`ctx.Response.HasStarted = true`) и при попытке установить StatusCode происходит исключение.

Определить терминальный middleware можно, к примеру, так:

```
        app.Run(context => Task.CompletedTask);
```

Но учтите, что вызывать `await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(...)` после вызова `await next()` категорически не рекомендуется, вы можете записать в ответ больше данных чем будет указано в заголовках 'Content-Length', что может привести к неверной трактовке содержимого на клиенте (он просто вычитает часть ответа).

Дополнительную информацию можете получить по [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)